# Loading Angular 2 templates at runtime?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm building an app to allow users to edit content based on predefined templates. I'd like to keep the templates outside of the app so that I can maintain them via an external API. How can I load them at runtime and apply bindings to them?

Comment: You can drop code into a tag on a page by specifying `[innerHTML]`, but that won't allow them to use angular bindings, only drop in HTML. Is that good enough?

Comment: you could have a service that you pass info to, and it returns the correct file.  E.g., `domain.com/templateservice/{componentname}`, and it would return `{componentname}.html`.

Comment: @Adam Yes the binding is a pretty important aspect of it. I'd like to load the html template then apply data to it.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear enough, you could set that service url I mentioned above to be the template url in the component.  With a url, the template file is lazy loaded when the component is loaded.

Comment: This depends on your toolchain. For example if you're using RequireJS you can load these files from the server with certain limitations. With any of these approaches you may run into complexities bundling your application. None of these approaches work with Angular 2 ahead of time compilation, but that may or may not be a concern for you.

Comment: One way would be to make each of these templates into a dedicated component in turn wrapped in a dedicated NgModule and load that as a lazy loaded feature module via a route. You could load this route into a <router-outlet>. This has drawbacks of course and introduces other complexities as passing data to this component will be complicated. I haven't tried it but it should work